# Dropzone file upload unknown issue

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I have a dropzone on a website where I am not restricting file types. Allowed files is set to default i.e null. But whenever I try to upload a specific file it shows its name but gives me error 'please choose a file to upload' which is my custom error.

```
if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length == 0) {
   $("#files_errors").text("Please select at least 1 file to upload.");
   errors = true;
}
```

but the problem is I am able to upload all files, exe, png, jpg, but file with name 'cs1.6 Full Non-Steam.exe'. I am able to upload other exe files but no this. I don't understand what can be the issue.

I have this above check in init. On btn click this check is performed because I have disabled auto upload of dropzone.

EDIT: I have tried to rename file to cs16-non-steam.exe with no luck

Comment: What happens if you rename the file to only have one `.`? Does it upload then? You might also want to try a strict equality check to see if your `if` block runs i.e. `(myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length === 0)` and if not, perhaps `myDropzone.getQueuedFiles()` is not returning what is normally expected for some reason.

Comment: @AndrewChart I just did. Changed it to cs16-non-steam.exe Same error

Comment: You might need to looking into something in your server config (e.g. `POST_MAX_SIZE` and `UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE` in apache) and see if your file conforms to those.

Comment: @AndrewChart No, i have checked that already.

Comment: @AndrewChart hmm for some reason for this file getQueued files is returning empty array

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this error, consider adding your complete dropzone configuration, also what browser are you using? which version of dropzone?